# what is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clicked' " in pyqt?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, attributeerror

I am trying to make my GUI switch to one another using this code

```
def open_beranda(self):
    uic.loadUi("gudangku_main-menu.ui", self)
def open_list(self):
    uic.loadUi("gudangku_list-item.ui", self)

class main_app(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(main_app, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("gudangku_main-menu.ui", self)
        self.beranda = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton_4")
        self.list_item = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton_3")

        self.beranda.clicked.connect(self.open_beranda)
        self.list_item.clicked.connect(self.open_list)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
UIWindow = main_app()
app.exec_()
```

but, it shows error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\pyqt5\gudangmainmenu.py", line 27, in <module>
    UIWindow = main_app()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\pyqt5\gudangmainmenu.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.beranda.clicked.connect(self.open_beranda)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clicked'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know what went wrong, please help

Comment: Are you completely sure that you have a QPushButton exactly named `pushButton_4` in `gudangku_main-menu.ui`? From your code, and the error, you either don't have a button named like that (remember that names are case sensitive!) or it's not a QPushButton type. Maybe you updated the UI but didn't *save* the file? Can you provide the contents of the ui file? Besides, remember that `uic.loadUi` automatically creates instance attributes, so there's no need to use `findChild()` for that: the `pushButton_4` will be automatically available as `self.pushButton_4` (assuming it *does* have that name).

Comment: The error message is telling you that `self.beranda` is `None`, which means that `self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton_4")` returned `None`.